# xcrun --show-sdk-version error, can't build with xcode on mojave

Tags: xcode, cmake, macos-mojave

I'm having problems getting a cmake project to compile with xcode on macOS Mojave.  Here's the error message associated with the build problem.

```
-- [polly] Used toolchain: Xcode (OS X default) / clang / LLVM Standard C++ Library (libc++) / c++11 support
xcodebuild: error: SDK "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk" cannot be located.
xcrun: error: unable to lookup item 'SDKVersion' in SDK '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk'

'xcrun --show-sdk-version' failed
```

Additionally, I've stumbled on the following incoherence.

```
localhost:~ ram$ xcrun --show-sdk-path
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk
localhost:~ ram$ xcrun --show-sdk-version
xcodebuild: error: SDK "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk" cannot be located.
xcrun: error: unable to lookup item 'SDKVersion' in SDK '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk'
```

I've also noticed that `xrun` is able to find 'MacOSX10.13.sdk', but not in the same path:

```
localhost:~ ram$ xcrun --sdk macosx10.13 --show-sdk-path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk
```

Does anyone know what might be the problem and, more importantly, how to fix this?

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure out how to fix this? I have the same problem :(

Comment: @AlextenBrink sorry I haven't found a fix to this problem.  I'm still looking though.

Comment: I found a workaround: add the `--sdk macosx` flag.

Comment: I also have this problem. Did anyone ever find a solution?